# Webbrowser not loading image C#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create a Windows Form Application which contains a webBrowser which displays images. For some reason some of the images are not displaying and i cant figure out why they are not displaying. 
I've tested some code and i figured out what code makes the image not display sometimes.

The code which causes the image not to display sometimes:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.SetAttribute("scroll", "no");
    var img = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
                         .Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();
    var w = img.ClientRectangle.Width;
    var h = img.ClientRectangle.Height;
    img.Style = string.Format("{0}: 100%", w > h ? "Width" : "Height");
}
```

However, i need this code for scaling images to the webbrowser format.

Image of a file not displaying in a webbrowser:

[image]

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Since this most likely depends on the specific src url it's hard to answer without an example to reproduce the issue. My bet is on a http redirect.

Comment: Its weird, if i click the -> button(next image) to quick, it does not show sometimes. Than i go back to that image(<-) and it is displaying.